# loss of control after redirect

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello stackoverflow experts.
I have a button on a web page.  When I click the button it runs a javascript function that makes an AJAX call to a .php program on a server and waits for the response.  When it comes, the handler function generates a nice report from the xml data it receives.  That all works fine.

Now the problem comes when the .php program gets a "not authenticated" response from the server it is requesting data from.  In that case it sends back a link to get authenticated.  Now the AJAX response handler has lost control because it did its job when it handled the "not autheticated" response.

If I click on the link I get taken away to another web site.  I then enter my username and password and then that site redirects the data back to the original requesting .php program.  The .php program just echos the data which then appears on my web page.  The entire web page is that data.  It is not handled by anything.

My question is how to regain control so that the data is once again handled properly and a nice report is generated?

Here is the html button code snippet:

```
Get report<button onclick='getCCDfromHV()'>Copy</button>
<div id="uploadResponse"></div>
```

Here is the getCCDfromHV javascript:

```
function getCCDfromHV() {
    document.getElementById("uploadResponse").innerHTML= "Connecting ...";
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            ccdXml = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            if (ccdXml.length < 400) { 
                document.getElementById("uploadResponse").innerHTML= ccdXml;   //not authenticated or expired
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("uploadResponse").innerHTML= "Report has been retrieved!<br>";
                var decoded = htmlDecode(ccdXml);
                xmlDom = createXmlDOM(decoded);  //create and fill global variable xmlDom
                createReport();
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","GetCCDfromHV.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here is somewhat simplified GetCCDfromHV.php:

```
<?php
$appId = file_get_contents('app2.id');
session_start();
ob_start();
ob_flush();

try {
  $hv = new HVRawConnector(
    $appId,
    file_get_contents('app.fp'),
    'app.pem',
    $_SESSION
  );

  $hv->connect();
  $hv->authenticatedWcRequest('GetPersonInfo');
  $recordId = $hv->getQueryPathResponse()->find('selected-record-id')->text();
  $thingId = '9c48a2b8-other-digits-identifying-data-type';  

  $hv->authenticatedWcRequest(
      'GetThings',
      '3',
      '<group max="30"><filter><type-id>' . $thingId . '</type-id></filter><format><section>core</section><xml/></format></group>',
      array('record-id' => $recordId)
    );

    print htmlentities($hv->getRawResponse()); //this prints the report which I format in javascript
    ob_flush();
}
catch (HVRawConnectorUserNotAuthenticatedException $e) {  //handle it here instead of returning to javascript?
  print "You are not authenticated! ";
  printAuthenticationLink();
}
catch (HVRawConnectorAuthenticationExpiredException $e) {
  print "Your authentication expired! ";
  printAuthenticationLink();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  print $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
  print $e->getCode() . '<br>';
  printAuthenticationLink();
}

function printAuthenticationLink() {
  global $appId;
  $url  = '"' .HVRawConnector::getAuthenticationURL($appId,'http' . (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_SSL']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$_SESSION) .'"';
  print '<a href=' .$url .'>Authenticate</a>';
  ob_flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to handle the redirection and everything within your javascript code and don't let the browser load any other page. a tutorial on how to do this won'T fit in here, especially without any minimal example.

Comment: show your javascript and php code related to your question

Comment: In the ajax response handler, check if response is `not authenticated`, if true, set a timer which periodically polls the server for the data. So long as it receives the `not authenticated` response, restart the timer. Once it receives the actual response, the timer can be canceled.

Comment: I'll try to put together example. Was trying to keep things as simple as possible.  I was thinking about it some more.  Maybe it would be possible to handle the "not authenticated" response within the .jsp.